# libGDX Google Play Services (BaseGameUtils) doesn't work on first attempt

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-services

I followed this [this](http://theinvader360.blogspot.com/2013/10/google-play-game-services-tutorial-example.html) tutorial, for getting Google Play Services inside my libGDX game for android. The first attempt I log in with  Google login inside my game it does not work. I don't get any bad errors it just doesn't get registered as logged in and I can not submit/view scores. The next attempt(s) to run the game everything works flawlessly (displays logged in banner and can submit scores, etc). If I sign out and log back in with a different account the same problem happens. I tested this on different phones with the same results.

I am hoping this is enough information to answer the question. My code is the same/similar to what the tutorial gives. Any ideas where my problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
This code was not properly added to my AndroidLauncher class.

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    _gameHelper.onStart(this);
}

 @Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    _gameHelper.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
    _gameHelper.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to make you aware that `GameHelper` or `BaseGameActivity` is deprecated and while you can still use it's not the "proper" way anymore. [Video on the subject](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1oSoaFLuTwM).

The new implementation is much easier to setup and is shown here: [Github](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples)

Nowadays you initialize `GoogleApiClient`and add all the listeners and Api's in there.

I have a working example of the NumberGame on my github page: [LibGDX NumberGame example](https://github.com/madmenyo/NumberGame). You still have to create add the ID's and create the achievements and scoreboards in the development console.